# android webview，I access a url,but i return some css data,how to make it be a page

Tags: android, webview

Here is url,http://news-at.zhihu.com/api/4/news/8696950
It returns some datas like "body":"

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using

Comment: String address = getIntent().getStringExtra("address");
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,address,"text/html","UTF-8",null);

Comment: the code returns a url I show before,

Comment: when I  use  webView.loadUrl(address),it returns css data

Comment: I guess the the url you are using doesn't return a valid html code, it returns a json object not html

Comment: I hope not.Many people use it .It  is a open api for ZhiHu news.

Comment: You need to parse the json response to extract the html code, after that you can use loadData method to interpret it in the webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your URL is not valid , try http://news-at.zhihu.com in webView this will work. that means your "http://news-at.zhihu.com/api/4/news/8696950" is may be in the JSON form or may be in  incorrect form(not valid).

hope this will help you .
Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.csdn.net/fanpeihua123/article/details/51210499.This is why I use that url. He says it is  html form.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to solve this problem.
First the url's data contains html code and css code,I should use JSON to get  html code and css code , and store them.And then use loadDataWithBaseURL() method to load the page.But I am not sure for the method's params.